# Finding a maximal ideal in the set of continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $X$ be the set of all continuous and real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. X is a commutative ring with pointwise addition and multiplication.
>   Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary.
>
> (1) Show that $I = \left\{f \in X \ \big\vert \  f(\alpha) = 0\right\}$ is a maximal ideal of $X$.
>
> (2) Show that $X/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

(1)

I tried to visualize this task. The only reason $I \neq X$ is position $\alpha$, where I cannot create another value than 0 using translation or rotation. If I take any function $f'$ for which $f'(\alpha) \neq 0$ applies, I can use the fact that $X$ contains all functions except for the ones being not 0 at $\alpha$, and can therefore create any continuous, real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$.

While this seems clear visualized at the paper, I have no clue how to formally write this down, can you please help me to formalize it? I'm especially stuck because I don't know how to formally write down *all continuous, real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$*.

(2)

I need to find a bijection between $X/I$ and $\mathbb{R}$, but don't understand why this is possible. As far as I understand $X/I$ are all continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that are not $0$ at position $\alpha$. But I can find more than one of those functions for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$ which is in $X/I$. So how could I find a bijection? Where is my mistake?

Comment: The *quotient* $X/I = \{f + I;~f ∈ X\}$ is a factor ring, *not* $X \setminus I = \{f ∈ X;~f \notin I\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) implies (1), for an ideal is maximal iff its quotient ring is a field.  As for (2), the map $e_\alpha \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, $e_\alpha(f) = f(\alpha)$, is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I looked around but didn't find a proof for "an ideal is maximal iff its quotient ring is a field", can you please explain why this applies?